# How can I apply a list as a variable number of arguments to the python print built-in?

Tags: python, python-2.7, printing

So you can apply a variable amount of arguments from a list to a normal function by doing this

```
someFunc(*[1,2,3])
```

But it doesn't work when I used the built-in print

```
    print(*[1,2,3])
          ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

How can I achieve the same effect with print?

Comment: Half-joking answer: switch to 3.X, where that syntax works :-)

Comment: Other half: `from __future__ import print_function`

Comment: https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3105/

Comment: Or if you don't want to do either of those: `def future_print(*args): for arg in args: print arg`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is that in python prior to python 3, `print` is a keyword of the language and not a function, so it doesn't work the same way. If you want to achieve a similar effect you can just make your own print function

```
def output(*args):
    print ' '.join(str(i) for i in args)
```

then use `output(*[1,2,3])`

Or if your version of python2 is recent enough (>= 2.6) you can do

```
from __future__ import print_function
```

to get the python 3 semantics.

Comment: It is for all versions of python >= 2.6